# iOS location manager firing off multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c

First off, I am very new to iOS Dev and Objective-C. So please excuse any stupid questions or code.

I have been testing the location services on an iPhone. I have this code that is fired off by a NSTimer:

```
- (void)startLocationTracking
{

  if(self.locationManager==nil){
    _locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    _locationManager.delegate=self;

    _locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    _locationManager.distanceFilter=1;

    self.locationManager=_locationManager;

  }

if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

  }

}
```

And here is my location manager function:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation    *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

[self timerLog];

NSString *deviceID = [self getUUID];

double lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
double alt = newLocation.altitude;
double dir = newLocation.course;
double spd = newLocation.speed;
double ha = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
double va = newLocation.verticalAccuracy;

NSDateFormatter *formatter;
NSString        *ts;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];

ts = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];   

[self geoTrackingWS :deviceID :lat :lon :alt :dir :spd :ha :va :ts];

[manager stopUpdatingLocation];

}
```

For some reason my function `geoTrackingWS` is firing off multiple times randomly. The NSTimer is running every 1 minute (just as a test) and sometimes it works fine and it calls the `geoTrackingWS` just once but other times it hits 2 or 3 times.

I have done logging and I can see my NSTimer is working fine and firing off as it should.

I have a feeling it has something to do with another application on my phone but I am not sure.

Any help or insight on this would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location manager usually has multiple ways of determining your location, including:

- cell tower triangulation;
- wifi network identification;
- GPS.

The first of those is least accurate but easiest to get, the second is usually more accurate but takes a while longer to figure out (as there's a network request for the lookup) and the final is most accurate but can take quite a while to figure out (searching for satellites, etc).

As a result it is expected behaviour that the location manager will respond with increasingly accurate results the longer it's left running. You can see the consequence of that when running Maps for example — it usually pins you down to quite a wide area quite quickly and then takes some time to get a more accurate estimate.

Comment: Is the point that I could be getting up to 3 because it is checking all 3 sometimes? That could be why my geoTrackingWS function runs anywhere from 1 - 3 times?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. On an iPhone (which has all three sensors; some devices only have one) it's quite conceivable that you'll get three estimates fired off. Each new one should be more accurate than the previous — try logging the horizontal and vertical accuracies to see whether that's what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think that is what it was. I ended up just catching the last one and it seems to be working well and it's more accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to create a new CLLocationManager instance more than once, which calling -startLocationTracking from a timer will do. From the look of your code, I think you want to call -startLocationTracking just once, and then the location API will send messages to your delegate (which you've specified as self) when it has new information. You might want to refresh your understanding of the delegate pattern, and look at some example code for using CLLocationManager. I hope that helps.